# Erro "Expression expected"

Tags: java, android

Peguei [esse código](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAEzL.png) que até certo ponto funcionou. Porém o método `updateLabel` eu não consigo fazer pois da problema:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso pegar a data selecionada do calendário. Estou usando uma forma em que ao clicar na editText, o calendário abre.

```
final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            updateLabel(myCalendar);

        }

    };

    editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new DatePickerDialog(AgendamentoActivity.this, date, myCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();

            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "8:00 - 9:00", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    private void updateLabel(Calendar) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss 'GMT'Z yyyy");
        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(myCalendar.getTime()));

        //editText.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que você está colocando seu método `updateLabel()` dentro do `onCreate` quando na verdade deveria estar fora. Veja um exemplo:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void updateLabel(){
    // aqui você coloca o código desejado
}
```

Comment: Não, está tudo fora do onCreate.

Comment: @GustavoSevero você tem que colocar o código na pergunta e não a imagem do código. Fica mais fácil te ajudar.

Comment: Coloquei a parte do código que está dando errado acima da foto

Comment: @GustavoSevero só isso não da pra descobrir o erro. ehe

Comment: Agora coloquei todo o código

Comment: Cara, o erro é exatamente o que estou te dizendo. você está colocando o método no lugar errado. Parte disso ai deveria estar dentro do oncreate e somente o método  updateLabel poderia estar fora.

Comment: OK, vou tentar isso.

Comment: Deu certo kkkkk Agora está dando outro erro depois que seleciono a data e clico em OK.

Comment: Não reconhece esse método:
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss 'GMT'Z yyyy");

Comment: @GustavoSevero isso ai já seria outro erro! Se quiser pode validar essa resposta e fazer outra pergunta com o novo erro! =D

Comment: Blz, é o que vou fazer.

Comment: @GustavoSevero boa sorte ai! =D

Answer (score 0):

Receba seu `Calendar` em `updateLabel(Calendar myCalendar)` e passe como argumento a esse mesmo método dentro do `onDateSet`.

Comment: Coloquei o novo errado que dá, após fazer o que vc sugeriu. Veja na descrição do post.

Comment: Poderia postar ela toda?

Comment: Coloquei todo o código